# How to pass strings directly into Angular2 EventBinding

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to do something like this, is It possible?

```
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" (click)="createComponent(MYSTRINGHERE)">Departamentos</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it, I just need to put single quotes on it

```
<li><a href="#" target="_blank" (click)="createComponent('t1')">Departamentos</a></li>
```